# app for office development with for outlook 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, outlook, office365

We are developing a Mail via App for Office " Hosted in office 2013 Client" I can develop the app and deploy it against my localhost for testing and developing... How do I go about creating different environment for this app... i.e. staging environment so I can deploy in an environment different than production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What different environment are you talking about?

Office Apps are supported by Office 2013 only. You can open a web browser and open the OWA to see how your App works there.